# WPF ListboxItems with ItemContainerStyle become unselectable

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

I coded the following ListBoxItemStyle to be able to place multiple elements into the listboxitem:

```
<Style x:Key="lbWithButton" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <xctk:IntegerUpDown Minimum="0" Value="0" Maximum="1000" Grid.Column="1"/>
               </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Unfortunately i cant select ListboxItems anymore. 
This also happens with only the textblock inside the listboxitem.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You probably better set an ItemTemplate instead of an ItemContainerStyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use ItemTemplate instead of ItemContainerStyle:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <xctk:IntegerUpDown Minimum="0" Value="0" Maximum="1000" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>    
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: And @RambaZamba, the reason your style does not work is because you are overriding the default control template. It is being selected logically, but you are not visually reflecting it in the control template.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This only works with an bound ItemsSource, right? Unfortunately the TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" is empty now. I can select the items tho and the IntegerUpDown is shown aswell.

Comment: @RambaZamba replace TemplateBinding by Binding